# Switch through JSON object values

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I have the following code to display an image inside of a carousel

```
<div class="carousel container px-0" *ngIf="module.type === 3">
  <div class="container px-0 position-absolute left">
    <div [ngStyle]="{ 'background-image': 'url(' + module.urlLeft + ')'}" class="img-container" (click)="decrease(i)">
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="container px-0 position-absolute right">
    <div [ngStyle]="{ 'background-image': 'url(' + module.urlRight + ')'}" class="img-container" (click)="increase(i)">
    </div>
  </div>

  <div [ngStyle]="{ 'background-image': 'url(' + module.urlCenter + ')'}" class="img-container">
  </div>
</div>
```

`module` is an array's object containing several image urls, the array contains multiple modules:

```
urlLeft: 'url'
urlCenter: 'url'
urlRight: 'url'
```

**How do I switch through all images of this specific module** (there might be several modules with carousels), e.g. by assigning the image from `urlLeft` to `urlCenter`, image from `urlCenter` to `urlRight` & image from `urlRight` to `urlLeft`?

I tried the following, but obviously this won't work since as soon as `urlLeft` is `urlCenter`, `urlRight` will also be `urlCenter`:

```
decrease(index) {
    this.modules[index].urlLeft = this.modules[index].urlCenter;
    this.modules[index].urlCenter = this.modules[index].urlRight;
    this.modules[index].urlRight = this.modules[index].urlLeft;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With ES6 it will be easy , Try this :

```
const { urlLeft , urlCenter , urlRight } = this.modules[index]; 
this.modules[index].urlLeft = urlCenter;
this.modules[index].urlCenter = urlRight;
this.modules[index].urlRight = urlLeft;
```

**Working Code Snippet:**

```js
var jsonObj = { first : 1 , second : 2 , third : 3 };
console.log( 'Before Exchange ====> ' , jsonObj);
const { first , second , third } = jsonObj;
jsonObj.first = second;
jsonObj.second = third;
jsonObj.third = first;
console.log( 'After Exchange ====> ' ,jsonObj);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also try an auxiliary variable to save urlLeft temporarily.

```
decrease(index) {
    const auxVar = this.modules[index].urlLeft;
    this.modules[index].urlLeft = this.modules[index].urlCenter;
    this.modules[index].urlCenter = this.modules[index].urlRight;
    this.modules[index].urlRight = auxVar;
}
```